# How to update and delete data using Luigi?

Tags: python, apache, luigi

what module can be use from luigi for update/delete data into database? i have use copy to table and sql alchemy for inserting data. for update and delete document is not clear how can it be achieved? please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is Postgres, you may be able to use PostgresQuery.
http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.postgres.html#luigi.postgres.PostgresQuery

Comment: i want to write for any database. is it possible to find out what point it failed and start update/ insert from that point? could it be achieve for any kind of database i mean writing common task and it can be use for any database?

Comment: Here is a working link: https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/luigi.contrib.postgres.html?highlight=Postgres#luigi.contrib.postgres.PostgresQuery